# Empty lines in php-errors.log

Tags: php, logging

I have a problem with my php-errors.log

It appears on a blank line on both with notepad++ and logexpert but not with notepad.

[image: logexpert]
[image: notepad++]
[image: notepad]

I use PHP 5.3.25

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Whats the actual problem? Just some editors not detecting  line endings correctly and showing blank lines between entries or is there actually a problem that I am not getting from your description?

Comment: Perhaps Notepad doesn't recognize Unix EOL. Does it really matter? Who uses notepad anyway?

Comment: read difference between windows EOL and unix eol and use proper editor that supports both.

Comment: @OneTrickPony, I would say it is actually notepad displaying it correctly and the others adding in an extra blank line as they are displaying /r/n as two lines instead of one line ending

Comment: I know that.
But would not it be a way to display correctly ?

Comment: Same problem here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321465/php-error-log-file-format-php-ini-error-log-directive-on-windows

Answer (score -1):

Find & Replace \n\n with \n?

Comment: @God the good way is replace \r by nothing because the endlines is \r\r\n

Comment: Any replacing is just affecting the symptoms and not the actual cause, so every time a new entry is added to the error log it will still have the wrong line ending