# PHP Error log has extra carriage returns?

Tags: php

I use WAMP, and in my php.ini file I have:

```
error_log = "d:/php_error.log"
```

When I open that file, I see:

```
[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in D:\....

[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() D:\....

[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP   2. Zend_Application->run()...

etc
```

The problem is that there are extra Carriage returns. I.e. I am expecting to rather have this:

```
[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in D:\....
[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() D:\....
[26-Jun-2013 05:35:57 UTC] PHP   2. Zend_Application->run()...
etc
```

What could be causing this?

**UPDATE**

I changed "error_append_string" and "error_prepend_string" to "". I also checked and the entries after a line are:

```
 [LINE]CR
 CRLF
 [LINE]CR
 etc
```

I.e. Carriage Returns and LineFeed symbols...

Comment: Do you have error_append_string in your php.ini: www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php? If yes, what's it's value?

Comment: What tool do you use to open the file? Can you use a hex editor to see what the end of line characters are?

Comment: I updated the question with more info.

Comment: I don't know, but has WAMP maybe a modified php source (PHP_EOL is `\r\n` and not `\r\r\n` according to source)? as far as I see in php source, error_append/prepend_string don't affect the error_log.

Comment: What editor do you use to view the log file? There are some bad that interprete the \r as new line.

Comment: Did you restart the web server after making the configuration changes?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321465/php-error-log-file-format-php-ini-error-log-directive-on-windows

Comment: @coderama did you figure it out?

Comment: For others still searching for a solution: It is definitely not the `error_prepend_string`setting. If you use a CR+LF within the error message error_log() will as well make CR+CR+LF from it (PHP 5.4.7, XAMPP package).

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the Windows build of PHP that has finally been fixed in PHP 7.1 but not 7.0 or earlier.  Simply swapping in PHP 7.1.11 in place of 7.0.25 on the same system (Windows 7, but also reproduced on Windows 10 and equally fixed by upgrade to PHP 7.1.9), same Apache (2.4.29), same php.ini diffs from the shipped php.ini.development, no other differences whatsoever, and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might have something to do with syslog messing you up. So PHP adds the `CR`, and then Windows' syslog goes in and puts an extra `CRLF` in it when processing the `log "line\n"` request.

See these related questions, where users had other problems with new line & error_log under other operating systems:

[PHP error_log outputting line breaks as literal "\n" strings on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319123/php-error-log-outputting-line-breaks-as-literal-n-strings-on-mac-osx)

[PHP error log and newline chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203664/php-error-log-and-newline-chars)

In particular, this may happen when the user that Apache runs as does not have permission to write to the file, or the `error_log` directive in your php.ini is unset (or defined as `syslog`). More details here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

As for the log file itself, you may try to experiment with it by giving it 777 permission, or creating the file yourself instead of letting the system create it (or vice-versa). Some users report different problems/solutions with each of these tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set `error_prepend_string` and `error_append_string`, but rather disable them completly, by commenting them(;):

```
;error_prepend_string
```

and

```
;error_append_string
```

Comment: They were previously disabled and U still got the carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the values of

```
error_prepend_string
```

and

```
error_append_string
```

on your .ini file.

Comment: I set them both to "" (blank) and it's still happening.