# error_log() adds "\r\r\n" to each error message

Tags: php

I use error_log() to save error messages in a file but for some reason newlines are made as "\r\r\n" in stead of "\r\n" and so i Notepad++ it looks like there are 2 newlines for each error message, so every other line is empty.

If i use this it works fine :

```
error_log($text . PHP_EOL, 3, $file);
```

But this will add "\r\r\n" :

```
error_log($text);
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Maybe check into the filemode the error log is opened with.  If opened in text mode on Windows, there may be some translation going on.  Especially if this does not match PHP_EOL (I assume that's \n). Just a hunch, though.

Comment: If you haven't seen these yet, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6321484/ and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46916